# How to properly clone a repository from github when mounting a docker image?

Tags: laravel, git, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Briefly about what I'm trying to do: push frontend, backend and other services into separate repositories and clone the source code from git during image mounting instead of using the usual `COPY . ./app`.

Here is my Dockerfile with the problem area:

```
# Install git.
RUN apk update && apk add git

# Install composer.
ENV COMPOSER_ALLOW_SUPERUSER 1
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/bin --filename=composer --quiet \
    && rm -rf /root/.composer/cache

# Cloning a laravel project from a private repository in github.
RUN git clone https://${USERNAME}:${TOKEN}@github.com/${USERNAME}/api.laravelTest.com.git

# Select the folder with the cloned repository as the working directory.
WORKDIR /var/www/html/api.laravelTest.com

# Install dependencies with the `composer install` command.
RUN composer install

# In the nginx configuration, the root directive has the path: /app/public,
# so we clone the contents of the api.laravelTest.com folder into the app folder.
RUN cp -r /var/www/html/api.laravelTest.com/. /app
```

The [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IvR8E.png) shows that the repository was indeed cloned, and the dependencies were installed, but all this is in the /var/www/html folder, but what about `RUN cp -r /var/www/html/api.laravelTest.com/. /app`?

There were no errors during mounting, the whole process was completed successfully, the containers are working.

I go to the [/app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHBAK.png) directory and do not see the laravel project files there, in other words, nothing was copied there from the /var/www/html/api.laravelTest.com folder and there were no errors during the execution of this command. Everything that is in this folder got there through volumes registered in docker-compose.yml.

Edited:

Containers for api in my docker-compose.yml:

```
api:
    ports:
      - "8002"
    build:
      context: api/nginx
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./api:/app
    depends_on:
      - api-php-fpm

api-php-fpm:
    build:
      context: api
      dockerfile: php-fpm/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./api:/app

api-php-cli:
    build:
      context: api/php-cli
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./api:/app
```

Api folder structure:

```
api
|
|--nginx
|  |
|  |-Dockerfile
|  |-conf.d
|    |
|    |-default.conf
|
|--php-fpm
|  |
|  |-Dockerfile
|
|--php-cli
   |
   |-Dockerfile
```

I also tried to simplify the dockerfile as much as possible:

```
FROM nginx:1.21.3-alpine

# Copy nginx configuration.
COPY ./conf.d /etc/nginx/conf.d

# Install git.
RUN apk update && apk add git

# Cloning a laravel project from a private repository in github.
RUN git clone https://${USER}:${TOKEN}@github.com/${USER}/api.laravelTest.com.git

# Try copy to app - does not work.
RUN cp -r ./api.laravelTest.com/. ./app

# Try copy to other folder, in this case copy to /usr/share/nginx/html - it works!
RUN cp -r ./api.laravelTest.com/. ./usr/share/nginx/html
```

I also tried to immediately clone the files from the repository to the app folder:

```
# Trying to immediately clone into the app folder (also does not work).
WORKDIR /app
RUN git clone https://${USER}:${TOKEN}@github.com/${USER}/api.laravelTest.com.git .
```

At the moment, any attempt to copy files or clone the repository, in other words, changing the contents of the app folder from the dockerfile, has no effect.

But, if I enter the container using the command:

```
root@:~/# docker exec -it <container_id> /bin/sh
```

And I execute next command inside the container, that it works:

```
cp -r ./api.laravelTest.com/. ./app
```

Comment: `Everything that is in this folder got there through volumes registered in docker-compose.yml.` do you mean you are mounting a volume on `/app` when you run your container from the image ? If yes how ? Which kind of mount (bind, docker volume) ? If a docker volume, was it empty when you mounted it ? This really looks like you are mounting existing contents over the image dir. In this case you will see only the mounted content. Please do not reply in comments: edit your answer. While you're at it, remove your screenshot and paste this as a code block and add you compose file.